# NumberFormatException when simulating the inquiry system of a small library

Tags: java, exception, catalog

I'm trying to type up a program that simulates the inquiry system of a small library, but I keep getting the same error.

The error is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10001        Emma"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at assg4_user.BookDemo.readCatalog(BookDemo.java:51)
    at assg4_user.BookDemo.main(BookDemo.java:20)
```

I'm not sure how to deal with it. If the code were to run correctly, then it would ask the user to input a book ID and if it's listed in the catalog, then it would output the Title, Author, etc. If not, it would run the "BookNotFoundException" Class.

Here's the text file for the catalog:

```
Book ID-----Title------------------------ISBN#------------------Author---------------Fiction/Non-Fiction
10001-------Emma---------------------0486406482----------Austen---------------F
12345-------My_Life-------------------0451526554----------Johnson-------------N
21444-------Life_Is_Beautiful-------1234567890----------Marin-----------------F
11111--------Horse_Whisperer------1111111111------------Evans----------------F
```

And here the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class BookDemo {

    static String catalogFile = "C:\\Users\\John\\workspace\\DataStructuresAssingments\\catalog.txt";
    static Book[] bookArray = new Book[100];
    static int bookCount = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, BookNotFoundException {

        // Read Catalog
        readCatalog();

        System.out.println("Enter book id:");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int bookId = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        while (bookId != 0) {
            bookSearch(bookArray, bookCount, bookId);
            bookId = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

        }
        in.close();
    }

    /**
     * Reads catalog file using try-with-resources
     */
    private static void readCatalog() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String line;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(catalogFile));) {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] str = line.split(" ");
                Book book = new Book(Integer.parseInt(str[0]), str[1], str[2], str[3], str[4].charAt(0));
                bookArray[bookCount] = book;
                bookCount++;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Search Books
     */
    private static void bookSearch(Book[] bookArr, int bookCount, Integer bookId) throws BookNotFoundException {
        boolean found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < bookCount; i++) {
            if (bookArr[i].getBookId().equals(bookId)) {
                System.out.println(bookArr[i]);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!found) {
            throw new BookNotFoundException("Book ID:" + bookId + " Not Found!");
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class Book {

    private Integer bookId;
    private String bookName;
    private String bookISBN;
    private String bookAuthorLastName;
    private String bookCategory;

    public Book() { }

    public Book(Integer bookId, String bookName, String bookISBN, String bookAuthorLastName, char category) {
        this.bookId = bookId;
        this.bookName = bookName;
        this.bookISBN = bookISBN;
        this.bookAuthorLastName = bookAuthorLastName;

        if (category == 'F') {
            this.bookCategory = "Fiction";
        }
        else if (category == 'N') {
            this.bookCategory = "Non-Fiction";
        }
    }

    // Getter methods skipped for brevity

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book id:" + bookId + ", Title:" + bookName + ", ISBN:" + bookISBN + ", Author:" + bookAuthorLastName + "," + bookCategory;
    }
}
```

```
public class BookNotFoundException extends Exception {

    public BookNotFoundException() { }

    public BookNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works fine by me, provided that I replace all occurrences of one or more dashes by a space within your file, *and* remove the header line..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there any tabs in the input file? or multiple spaces? perhaps you should split the lines like this:

```
            String[] str = line.split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 1):

NumberFormatException is a RuntimeException so it will 'slide by' your normal exception handling if it is not handled explicitly. So surround your parseInt with a try-catch like this

```
try {
    bookId = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    throw new BookNotFoundException();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I'm still running into the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I won't give you the whole solution or the logic about your problem. You are getting this error because you are trying to parse a String to Integer (`"10001 Emma"`). `Integer.parseInt("1001")` will work only if the parameter passed is int and does not contain any character.

**EDIT**

According to your data your `bookId` contains only int data. Now if you want to force the user to input only int data replace `a` with `b` portion below:

a)

```
int bookId = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
```

b)

```
int bookId;

    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            bookId = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        }catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Only integer input is accepted.");
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
```

Do the same for line 27 : `bookId = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());`

Answer (score 1):

`readCatalog` is failing with `parseInt`. To debug, print the parameter to `parseInt` to the console (in this case, `str[0]`). If it's not what you expect, time to print the whole line and start experimenting with how [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) works in Java and how to get it to parse your line correctly.

Comment: I think in reality his file contains data like below:
`10001 Emma 0486406482 Austen F` not `10001-------Emma---------------------0486406482----------Austen---------------F`

because he gets error at line 20 : `at assg4_user.BookDemo.main(BookDemo.java:20)`

Although in that case space  is not allowed.

Comment: If that were the case '10001' would parse cleanly instead of including 'Emma'. The truth is we just don't know, and the process of debugging is exactly the way I would approach similar unexpected behavior in something I was trying to do.

Comment: if the file contained `10001-------Emma---------------------0486406482----------Austen---------------F` he would have got exception like : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10001-------Emma---------------------0486406482----------Austen---------------F"` not just `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10001        Emma"`. Also he is asking for input here rt?

Answer (score 1):

I can only reproduce your error by putting a tab behind `10001`.

```
10001⟶Emma     0486406482
```

<sup>(`⟶` being a tab character)</sup>

You split by a single space, so `10001` and `Emma` are not two elements, but one array element, and, of course, it is not parsable as an integer.

You can fix this by splitting by one or more [whitespace characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character). Since `split()` accepts a regular expression, you can simply write this:

```
String[] str = line.split("\\s+");
```

---

Oh, and a few more things:

- The properties in the `Book` class all start with "book". It's generally unnecessary to repeat the class name. So `id`, `name`, `isbn`, `authorLastName` and `category` will be fine.
- You could use a `List` instead of an array. It's more elegant and you don't have to declare the size at start. Also, the `bookCount` variable is no longer needed, because you can get the size with `bookArray.size()`.
- With Java 8, you can use functional programming to search for the book.

  ```
  private static void search(List<Book> books, Integer bookId) throws BookNotFoundException {
      boolean found = books.stream()
          .anyMatch(t -> {
              System.out.println(t);
              return Objects.equals(t.getBookId(), bookId);
          });

      if (!found) {
          throw new BookNotFoundException("Book ID: " + bookId + " Not Found!");
      }
  }
  ```